# How can i solve the error "no module named stastics in python"?

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried this program and i am getting an error no attribute error?

```
import statistics

data = [11, 21, 11, 19, 46, 21, 19, 29, 21, 18, 3, 11, 11]

x = statistics.mean(data)
print(x)

y = statistics.median(data)
print(y)

z = statistics.mode(data)
print(z)
```

Comment: what version of python are you using? this code works fine in python 3.7. ([`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html?highlight=statistics#module-statistics) was introduced in 3.4 and not backported to 2.7).

Comment: Add the error you are getting as well. Also specify excatly which version of python you are using?